# How can I put a specific condition for resampling in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have one three hourly time series dataframe. I want to calculate daily average by considering this condition 
“ if there is more than 5 three hourly missing data in a day, consider that day as missing value”.

For Example I have the following time series:

```
2007-01-01 00:00:00   NaN
2007-01-01 03:00:00   NaN
2007-01-01 06:00:00   NaN
2007-01-01 09:00:00   NaN
2007-01-01 12:00:00   NaN
2007-01-01 15:00:00   NaN
2007-01-01 18:00:00  39.2
2007-01-01 21:00:00  43.2
2007-01-02 00:00:00  41.9
2007-01-02 03:00:00  40.6
2007-01-02 06:00:00  40.2
2007-01-02 09:00:00  39.3
2007-01-02 12:00:00  39.5
2007-01-02 15:00:00  39.6
2007-01-02 18:00:00  38.0
2007-01-02 21:00:00  38.0
2007-01-03 00:00:00   NaN
```

What I got is:

```
df.resample('D',how='mean')            
2007-01-01       **41.2000**
2007-01-02       **39.6375**
2007-01-03       **NaN**
```

What I am looking for is:

```
2007-01-01        **NaN**
2007-01-02        **39.6375**
2007-01-03        **NaN**
```

I would appreciate if anyone guides me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another alternative that might appear simpler (though learning to apply functions to groups is a great idea!)

```
# Resample by mean
df_resample = df.resample('D',how='mean')
# Resample by count of value
df_count = df.resample('D',how='count')
# Filter on those that have less than 3 answers and set it to nan
df_resample.ix[df_count['values'] < 3, 'value'] = np.nan

# Display result
df_resample
            values
time_index 
2007-01-01  NaN
2007-01-02  39.6375
2007-01-03  NaN
```

Comment: For information, Jianxun's answer is faster that this alternative: 1.7ms versus 1.87 ms per loop for mine (for 1000 loops) (10% diff)

Comment: Where is @Jianxun answer?

Comment: Gone, apparently.